# Identity(1,1) in Microsoft SQL Server - Is there a practical reason to ever use values other than 1,1 for seed/increment?

Tags: sql-server

I'm teaching a Microsoft SQL Server course and a student asked if there was a practical reason why we would ever set the auto increment as something other than 1,1 (seed starting at 1, increment by 1). Is there a practical reason why we would ever set the seed to something higher or increment by a value other than 1? Shouldn't it not matter as long as that value is unique?

If there is no practical reason, why do we have the option to set those values for Identity in Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: You may apply Identity on an existing table. In this case you have to set the seed equal to the max id of the table + 1

Comment: A common practical reason is when the key is used outside the database, and there is a desire to conceal the starting point - for example, it is common for firms to start their order numbers at (for example) 1001 instead of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of practical reasons for having a configurable start value :

- You may want to insert a few predefined records with well-known IDs, eg `Missing`, `Unknown` and `Not Applicable` records in a dimension or lookup table should probably have predefined IDs. New rows should get IDs outside the range of the predefined numbers.
- After loading or replicating data with existing ID values, new records should get IDs that don't conflict with the imported data. The easiest way to do this is by setting the starting ID somewhere above the maximum imported ID.
- `TRUNCATE TABLE` resets the IDENTITY value. To avoid generating duplicate IDs you need to reseed the table with [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-forcing-the-current-identity-value-to-a-new-value) and set the current value to something other than 1

There are certainly dozens of other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a signed integer and start at 1, you're only using half the available range. Default should really be to start at minimum for the data type, for example -2 billion for 32 bit int.

In some cases, you may want to combine data from multiple tables. In that case each table should keep a separate range of ids. You could have each table start at a different number to prevent overlaps. For example start one at 1 and another one at 1 billion. Or you could use odd numbers for one (1,2) and even numbers for the other (2,2).

Comment: If you want greater range, use a `bigint`. Negative IDs make it a lot harder to work with the data, which is why you *don't* see them, except for "special" records, eg predefined `Missing`, `Empty`, `Invalid` records. For multiple tables, you can use a `SEQUENCE` instead of an `IDENTITY` and not have to worry about ranges.

Comment: can you give an example of difficulties you experience with negative integers?

Comment: Yes, they confuse the humans that are meant to use the data, for no real gain. Negative values *are* used as well-known IDs too. As for the range argument, If 2^31 values aren't enough, simply doubling the range won't be enough either. That's why system tables use `bigint` IDs instead of negative `int`s

Comment: Identity is really meant for a system id/pk, not necessarily meant for humans. As a general rule, you should use the smallest data type that fits the scenario, so going to bigint where int is sufficient is not the best practice

Comment: GUIDs are not "easy" for humans to read / understand but we seem to have overcome that. I'll agree with under - ignoring half the domain of the datatype for "ease-of-use" is not a compelling reason.